# Hibernate or save before switch between OSs

Tags: multi-boot, operating-systems, hibernate, bootloader, boot-manager

I have multiple OS, Windows and Linux via multi-boot (windows boot-loader), but every time I want to switch between them I must shutdown one OS to boot up other one, has there any way to hibernate or save current opened windows and programs before switch to other OS, I know I can do this with hyper-v in windows but I don't want to have full operating system just for boot switching, I just want a minimal boot-loader because I only have 4 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You will still need a 3rd OS to control the hibernate of the 2 main OSses from the hypervisor. I'm fairly certain there doesn't exist anything like that at boot-loader level...
Most minimalist approach would probably be a minimal Linux install with the Hypervisor and both main machines as VM's. Windows is just too heavy to use as control OS.

Anyway: I sincerely doubt it is going to be must faster then dual-booting for the Windows part. (Windows 10 with the fast-boot option already does a hibernate in stead of a real shutdown.)
And you have the added disadvantage of not being to able to use the full hardware capabilities (e.g. video-performance) when running as a VM. Possibly also a lot of issues with USB devices.

Answer (score 0):

Swap your bootloaders.

Currently you have Windows's `bootmgr` as the primary bootloader. It can either load Windows or chainload Linux's bootloader - probably GRUB2. GRUB2 will then boot into Linux. When `bootmgr` detects hibernated Windows, it will always resume it rather than let you select OS.

You can make GRUB2 your primary bootloader and add `bootmgr` as a boot option. This way `bootmgr` doesn't start first, so you can choose to boot into Linux despite having a hibernated Windows instance.

This setup has its limitations: Linux will let you access Windows partition only in read-only mode while Windows is hibernated. It's a reasonable thing to do, otherwise you could damage the filesystem. That's most likely the rationale behind `bootmgr` forcing a resume in the first place.